# can any algorithm be implemented into hadoop streaming mapreduce work?

Tags: python, algorithm, hadoop, mapreduce, streaming

I have a data set:

user       feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4 ...

user1      f11       f12      f13      f14 ...

user2      f21       f22      f23      f24 ...

I have an algorithm to apply to this data set, so that, for each user, we can calculate the similarity score between this user and other users:

```
      score{user_i}=algorithm(dict{user_i},dict{user_k})
```

And the dict{user_i}=[f11,f12,f13,f14] is a hash.

for each user, after we calculate the similarity between the user and all the other users, we sort the similarity scores by descending order, and give the output.

Here is the reducer.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import random, csv,sys;

def similarity(list1,list2):
  list3=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
  list4=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]      
  if len(list1)>=5:
     if list1[3]==list2[3]:
        list3[3]=1
        list4[3]=1
     else:
        list3[3]=0
        list4[3]=1
    if list1[4]==list2[4]:
        list3[4]=1 
        list4[4]=1
    else:
        list3[4]=0 
        list4[4]=1
     if list1[5]==list2[5]:
        list3[5]=1
        list4[5]=1
     else:
        list3[5]=0
        list4[5]=1
     if list1[6]!="\N" and list2[6]!="\N" and abs(float(list1[6].split("/")            [2][0:4])-float(list2[6].split("/")[2][0:4]))<=2:
    list3[6]=1
    list4[6]=1
 else:
    list3[6]=0
    list4[6]=1
 if list1[7]!="\N" and list1[7]!="\N" and abs(float(list1[7])-float(list2[7]))<=20:
    list3[7]=1 
    list4[7]=1
 else:
    list3[7]=0 
    list4[7]=1
 list3[8]=1
 list4[8]=1
 if list1[9]!="\N" and list2[9]!="\N" and list1[9]!="" and list2[9]!="" and abs(float(list1[9])-float(list2[9]))<=20:
    list3[9]=1 
    list4[9]=1
 else:
    list3[9]=0 
    list4[9]=1
 if list1[10]!="\N" and list2[10]!="\N" and list1[10]!=0 and list2[10]!=0 and abs(float(list1[10])-float(list2[10]))<=3:
    list3[10]=1
    list4[10]=1
 else:
    list3[10]=0
    list4[10]=1
 set_1=list3[3:11]
 set_2=list4[3:11]
 inter_len=0
 noninter_len=0
 for i in range(len(set_1)):
   if set_1[i]==set_2[i]:
      inter_len=inter_len+1
   if set_1[i]!=set_2[i]:
      noninter_len=noninter_len+1
 jaccard=inter_len/float(inter_len+noninter_len) 
 if list1[0]==list2[0]:
    genre=1
 elif list1[0][0:6]==list2[0][0:6]:
    genre=0.5
 else:
    genre=0
 if list1[1]==list2[1]:
    rating=1
 elif list1[1][0:2]==list2[1][0:2]:
    rating=0.5
 else:
    rating=0
 if list1[2]!="" and list2[2]!="" and len(set.intersection(set(list1[2].split(",")),set(list2[2].split(","))))>0:
    target=1
 else:
    target=0
 return jaccard+genre+rating+target
  else:
    print "Trim data incomplete"





it=0
trim_id=sys.argv[0]

dict={ }
score={ }

 for line in sys.stdin:
    line=line.strip().split("\t")
      dict[line[0]]=line[1:12]


keylist=dict.keys()
keylist.sort()

for key in keylist:
    if key!=trim_id:
       score[key]=similarity(dict[key],dict[trim_id])

iter=0
for key, value in sorted(score.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,k),reverse=True):
    print "%s" % (key)
    iter=iter+1
    if iter>=10:
       break
```

here is the bash file for the hadoop streaming:

```
hadoop fs -rmr /tmp/somec/some/

hadoop jar *.jar \
       -input /user/hive/warehouse/fb_text/ \
       -output /tmp/somec/some/ \
       -mapper "cat" \
       -reducer "jac.py" \
       -file jac.py \
```

The fb_text is tab delimitered. And it is good. I tested a word count hadoop streaming job on it. It ran smoothly.

And here is the hadoop streaming error:

```
rmr: DEPRECATED: Please use 'rm -r' instead.
14/05/14 00:31:55 INFO fs.TrashPolicyDefault: Namenode trash configuration: Deletion     interval = 0 minutes, Emptier interval = 0 minutes.
Deleted /tmp/somec/some
14/05/14 00:31:57 WARN streaming.StreamJob: -file option is deprecated, please use     generic option -files instead.
packageJobJar: [jac.py] [/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.0-0.cdh5b2.p0.27/lib/hadoop-    mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.2.0-cdh5.0.0-beta-2.jar]     /tmp/streamjob3048667246321733915.jar tmpDir=null
14/05/14 00:31:58 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at     ip-10-0-0-190.us-west-2.compute.internal/10.0.0.190:8032
14/05/14 00:31:59 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at    ip-10-0-0-190.us-west-2.compute.internal/10.0.0.190:8032
14/05/14 00:32:02 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/05/14 00:32:04 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
14/05/14 00:32:04 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job:     job_1399599059169_0110
14/05/14 00:32:05 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application     application_1399599059169_0110
14/05/14 00:32:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://ip-    10-0-0-190.us-west-2.compute.internal:8088/proxy/application_1399599059169_0110/
14/05/14 00:32:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1399599059169_0110
14/05/14 00:32:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1399599059169_0110 running in uber mode : false
14/05/14 00:32:13 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/05/14 00:32:19 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
14/05/14 00:32:20 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
14/05/14 00:32:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1399599059169_0110_r_000001_0,     Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed     with code 127
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:459)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:165)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:160)

14/05/14 00:32:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id :     attempt_1399599059169_0110_r_000003_0,     Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:459)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:165)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:160)
```

I am wondering why.

My hadoop streaming jar is good. I tested a word count example, it ran smoothly.

And this python code works fine on local linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

You are only seeing half the error on the screen. It basically says "The python script failed".

You need to go to the job tracker UI, find the job, click on a failing map task and look at the logs. Hopefully Python wrote something to stderr that will help you.

For extra debugging, consider adding some helpful "println" messages in your script.

A good tip for testing locally is not to just run the Python script, but run it in a similar way that Streaming will use it. Try:

cat data | map.py | sort | reduce.py

Last:
The output of both mapper and reducer should be \t (i.e. key and value separated by tab).

Comment: Hi, thank you. We run this mapreduce job on AWS, no job tracker UI. I did something like cat data|map.py|reduce.py locally. It works. So, I am confused. I am wondering based on my description, do you agree that hadoop mapreduce streaming can do any algorithm?

Comment: so the output of both mapper and reducer should be \t, is that possible that the mapper output, it has this output:Key1\tKey2\tValue1\tValue2\tValue3...i.e. multiple keys and multiple values, or value in a list in python?

Comment: is that possible that the reducer step only output values? i.e. no key, one column of values.